# Live server (vs code) extension scales up the whole webpage

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have been using live server to view my page, Later when I started backend for my project I stared using xampp, but all the front end I have designed relative to live server extension scaled up my whole website( I don't know what is the problem, I'm new), when I run server using xampp, I could see huge difference.

Mypage Using Live server extionsion in vscode

[image]

My page using xampp server or just clicking html from project folder

[image: image-desc]

Please help, been stuck with this problem for a while

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely your real webbrowser, or your inside-vscode-webbrowser is set to a different zoom level.

Try pressing `CTRL-0` to reset the zoom back to normal while looking at your site (in either of the 2 browsers).

Answer (score 0):

If you noticed, every time you open VS Code and start Live Server, you are asked which file to load from the project folder. For example, if you have a `main.html` and a `style.css` file, as soon as the Live Server stabilizes, you will be asked which of the 2 files to load. It is usually best to turn off and reconnect the extension, choosing again which file will be loaded. Try to select the xaamp file for the backend directly, it should load both main.html and xaamp. If it doesn't work, try read this  for your problem: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/137